# Проверка сервера на функционирование

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Код ниже загружает файл в директорию проекта:

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

try {
  const file = fs.createWriteStream(`file.pdf`);
  const request = http.get(`http://http.pdf`, response => {
    response.pipe(file);
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Когда сервер падает, файл не удается загрузить и выпадает ошибка, которую не удается отловить через `try {} catch () {}`

```
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT ***
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: ***,
  port: 80
}
```

Как проверить сервер на функционирование?

Comment: Что значит "не удается отловить"? Почему не удается? Может, вы её не там ловите?

Comment: @andreymal, приведенный код лежит внутри `try catch`

Comment: Это ни о чём не говорит, потому что ошибка может возникать в каком-нибудь коллбэке, а значит try-catch должен стоять именно в коллбэке, а не абы где. Приведите [mcve] чтобы было о чём предметно разговаривать

Comment: Точнее даже не так — если вы используете асинхронный модуль и выполняете асинхронные действия, значит и обработку ошибок нужно делать асинхронную, добавив коллбэк на событие `error` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328540

Comment: @andreymal, это помогло